# $p \equiv 5 \mod8\Rightarrow p=(2x+y)^{2}+4y^{2}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If $p \equiv 5 \mod8$ , then $p=(2x+y)^{2}+4y^{2}$,for some x and y integers.
Thanks

Here is my approach:

I know $p \equiv 5 \mod8\Rightarrow $

$p \equiv 1 \mod4\Rightarrow $

$n^{2}+m^{2}=p\equiv 5 \mod8 \Rightarrow$

from $t^{2}\equiv 0,1~or ~4 \mod8$ we get $n^{2} \equiv 1 \mod8$ and $m^{2} \equiv 4 \mod8$

$\Rightarrow n=4x-1$ and $m=2y$.

So I need $n=2x+y$.

Comment: From $m^{2}\equiv4 mod(8)$ you know that $y$ is odd. Also $n$ is odd. So $n-y$ is even. You can make it $2x$

Comment: Are you sure that you are not missing any context, such as $y$ is odd.

Comment: @Tian ah i see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$p \equiv 5 \mod8\Rightarrow $

$p \equiv 1 \mod4\Rightarrow $

$n^{2}+m^{2}=p\equiv 5 \mod8 \Rightarrow$

from $t^{2}\equiv 0,1~or ~4 \mod8$ we get $n^{2} \equiv 1 \mod8$ and $m^{2} \equiv 4 \mod8 \Rightarrow$

n is odd and $ m=2y$ where y is odd $\Rightarrow$

n-y is even $\Rightarrow$

n-y=2x and m=2y $\Rightarrow$

$p=(2x+y)^{2}+4y^{2}\square$.